# How to set X-axis limit for years in a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have a plot as below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df[['Year','Unemployment with primary education (% of total 
unemployment)','Unemployment with secondary education (% of total 
unemployment)','Unemployment with tertiary education (% of total 
unemployment)']].set_index('Year').plot()

plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

I would like to limit the x-axis upto 2005 only. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have your data, but if `'year'` is a simple number, you can set the limits by calling

```
plt.xlim(None, 2005)
```